# How do you like the new Ribbon Controls in D2009?

Tags: delphi, ribbon

How do they compare to the DevXpress ones or the original MSOffice ones.
Are they worth investing time in them (for practical usage now, not academic curiosity which I'll do anyway)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, the new ribbon control implements the entire specification as laid out by Microsoft.  The only issue I noticed was a slight flicker when the form was resized which caused one of the sections to collapse or expand.

Worth spending time in?  Definitely, as they are lighter weight and its a matter of time before someone gets rid of the flicker (could be as simple as a lockwindowupdate inserted in the source?).  It doesn't hurt to use the Delphi action manager, from which all is based.

Comment: Yep, I also notice that slight flicker on my Windows XP machine, but not on my Vista machine (which also happens to be a lot faster).  It happens for me when I change tabs too.

Comment: Don't misuse LockWindowUpdate() for that.
See http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see with them so far, is the lack of Glass Frame implementation on Windows Vista (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170282/delphi-2009-ribbon-controls-glass-frame)), unless someone has found a way to make that work.  The only part which may not be a problem for youself is there doesn't appear to be a way to customise the theme, which I know some people would like to do in their applications.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the DevExpress ribbon control is much more complex than it needs to be.  i own the DevExpress ribbon control but converted to using the delphi TRibbon.  the delphi TRibbon isn't perfect either but i've learned to avoid these problems.