# Delphi 2009 Ribbon Controls - Glass Frame

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl, ribbon, aero-glass

I've been starting to use the new inbuilt Ribbon controls in Delphi 2009 and use the custom frame so the Application button and Mini-toolbar slide up onto the Window Frame, but I'm wondering if on Vista it should use the glass effect like Office 2007 does, and if so how I would enable this setting.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear that that CodeGear implementation of the Ribbon control is compatible with the glass frame.  Something about the way it draws disables it.

Comment: That is unfortunate, really diminishes the usefulness of the ribbon in regards to nicer UI design.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tao, if the answer was helpful, you can use the upvote button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml

It interfaces the Native Ribbon Framework and works beautifully.